# length of each element in an array Java

Tags: java, arrays

Here is what I'm trying to use. The method .length doesn't work for anything I try, so I'm not even sure where to begin.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class LengthsOfStrings {
public static ArrayList<Integer> lengths(ArrayList<String> list) {
    ArrayList<Integer> lengthList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int nums: lengthList) {
        System.out.println(nums.length());  
    }


    return lengthList;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("Ciao");
    list.add("Moi");
    list.add("Benvenuto!");
    list.add("badger badger badger badger");
    ArrayList<Integer> lengths = lengths(list);

    System.out.println("The lengths of the Strings: " + lengths);
}
}
```

Comment: `int nums` this is primitive.

Comment: You pass 'list' as parameter to your lengths method, but you don't use it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to iterate through a single `int` instead of the strings array. Change

```
for (int nums: lengthList) {
    System.out.println(nums.length());  
}
```

to

```
for (String str: list) { // loop through the list of strings
    lengthList.add(str.length()); // store the individual length of each string
}
```

so as to loop through the list of strings, collect the `length` of each string & store it int the `Arraylist` that you `return` later.

Answer (score 0):

In the following code:

```
ArrayList<Integer> lengthList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int nums: lengthList) {
        System.out.println(nums.length());  
    }
```

You are creating an `ArrayList<Integer> lengthList` which is empty and trying to iterate over it.

I think you want to iterate over `list` something like this:

```
for (String s: list) {
    lengthList.add(s.length());
    System.out.println(s.length());  
}
```

and add `length()` of each `String` to `lengthList` in each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Here in your code you need to update at 2 places:

1) In lengths method you are passing list(`ArrayList<String> list`), but you are not iterating over that you. You have to iterate over this list.
2) In the for loop you have made the variable as int, while the list is of type String. So update your code like below :

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> lengths(ArrayList<String> list) {

    for (String nums: list) {
        System.out.println(nums.length());  
    }

    return lengthList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For **Java 8** user

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {

  List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("Hi", "Hello", "how r u?");
  List<Integer> lengthList = lengths(strings);
  lengthList.forEach(System.out::println);
}

public static List<Integer> lengths(List<String> list) {

 return list.stream().mapToInt(s -> s.length()).boxed()
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
//OR
return list.stream().mapToInt(String::length).boxed()
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```